# Remove www from subdomain and then redirect to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, no-www

I'm trying to add some rules to an .htaccess file in a subdomain to:

1. Remove the www from the subdomain (if present) (E.g.: www.subdomain.domain.com to subdomain.domain.com)
2. Redirect to the /beta subdirectory (E.g: subdomain.domain.com to subdomain.domain.com/beta)

I have the second part only:

```
# Redirect to /beta
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /beta [L]
```

I've seen a couple of examples here in StackOverflow but they seem to work only for domains, not subdomains. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect old domain to new domain this should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subdomain.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Note that I omitted the `L` directive here (`[R=301,L]`) because you are probably going to add the second directive (/beta redirect) right after this.